# Mongodb replicaset and sharding cluster always crashed

Tags: mongodb, crash, sharding, replicaset

I have 13 machines in Azure cloud, 3 configuration servers, 3 * 3 mongod instances (3 sharding server with 3 members of replica set), only one mongos server. I have ran into quite a lot of problems and couldn't step further. Mongod instances always crashed, below is the backtrace.

```
2017-03-08T06:56:08.759+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Successfully connected to mongocfg1:27017
2017-03-08T06:57:16.334+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T06:57:16.339+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T06:59:40.776+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T06:59:40.781+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:01:39.677+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:01:39.682+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:04:11.820+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:04:11.828+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:08:32.057+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:08:32.067+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:09:50.806+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:09:50.811+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:11:22.987+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:11:22.994+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:15:45.144+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:15:45.149+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:18:13.920+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:18:13.925+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:19:37.225+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:19:37.232+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:23:01.838+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:23:01.842+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:26:08.837+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Connecting to mongocfg1:27017
2017-03-08T07:26:08.842+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Successfully connected to mongocfg1:27017
2017-03-08T07:26:10.871+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:26:10.876+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:28:19.745+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:28:19.750+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:30:19.073+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:30:19.086+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:36:37.405+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:36:37.413+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:39:38.799+0000 I NETWORK  [conn17] received client metadata from 10.1.0.24:49312 conn17: { driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.4.2" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", architecture: "x86_64", version: "16.04" } }
2017-03-08T07:41:18.115+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:41:18.129+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:42:34.092+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:42:34.098+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:43:31.773+0000 I REPL     [replication-644] Restarting oplog query due to error: ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out, request was RemoteCommand 16502602 -- target:mongo1:27017 db:local expDate:2017-            03-08T07:43:31.770+0000 cmd:{ getMore: 13601610393, collection: "oplog.rs", maxTimeMS: 5000, term: 18, lastKnownCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp 1488958996000|178, t: 18 } }. Last fetched optime (with hash): { ts: Timestamp 1488958997000|33, t: 18 }[-6472237239882359497]. Restarts remaining: 3
2017-03-08T07:43:31.774+0000 I REPL     [replication-644] Scheduled new oplog query Fetcher source: mongo1:27017 database: local query: { find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1488958997000|33 } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 60000, term: 18 } query metadata: { $replData: 1, $ssm: { $secondaryOk: true } } active: 1 timeout: 10000ms shutting down?: 0 first: 1 firstCommandScheduler: RemoteCommandRetryScheduler request: RemoteCommand 16502628 -- target:mongo1:27017 db:local cmd:{ find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1488958997000|33 } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 60000, term: 18 } active: 1 callbackHandle.valid: 1 callbackHandle.cancelled: 0 attempt: 1 retryPolicy: RetryPolicyImpl maxAttempts: 1 maxTimeMillis: -1ms
2017-03-08T07:43:57.979+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:43:57.990+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:44:08.898+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Connecting to mongocfg2:27017
2017-03-08T07:44:08.903+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Successfully connected to mongocfg2:27017
2017-03-08T07:48:47.997+0000 I REPL     [replication-651] Restarting oplog query due to error: ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out, request was RemoteCommand 16569116 -- target:mongo1:27017 db:local expDate:2017-03-08T07:48:47.996+0000 cmd:{ getMore: 15723258409, collection: "oplog.rs", maxTimeMS: 5000, term: 18, lastKnownCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp 1488959313000|8, t: 18 } }. Last fetched optime (with hash): { ts: Timestamp 1488959317000|94, t: 18 }[2970473222715518783]. Restarts remaining: 3
2017-03-08T07:48:47.999+0000 I REPL     [replication-651] Scheduled new oplog query Fetcher source: mongo1:27017 database: local query: { find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1488959317000|94 } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 60000, term: 18 } query metadata: { $replData: 1, $ssm: { $secondaryOk: true } } active: 1 timeout: 10000ms shutting down?: 0 first: 1 firstCommandScheduler: RemoteCommandRetryScheduler request: RemoteCommand 16569148 -- target:mongo1:27017 db:local cmd:{ find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1488959317000|94 } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 60000, term: 18 } active: 1 callbackHandle.valid: 1 callbackHandle.cancelled: 0 attempt: 1 retryPolicy: RetryPolicyImpl maxAttempts: 1 maxTimeMillis: -1ms
2017-03-08T07:48:59.348+0000 I REPL     [replication-644] Restarting oplog query due to error: ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out, request was RemoteCommand 16569172 -- target:mongo1:27017 db:local expDate:2017-03-08T07:48:59.348+0000 cmd:{ getMore: 14887779559, collection: "oplog.rs", maxTimeMS: 5000, term: 18, lastKnownCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp 1488959323000|14, t: 18 } }. Last fetched optime (with hash): { ts: Timestamp 1488959328000|24, t: 18 }[6103377339294692895]. Restarts remaining: 3
2017-03-08T07:48:59.349+0000 I REPL     [replication-644] Scheduled new oplog query Fetcher source: mongo1:27017 database: local query: { find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1488959328000|24 } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 60000, term: 18 } query metadata: { $replData: 1, $ssm: { $secondaryOk: true } } active: 1 timeout: 10000ms shutting down?: 0 first: 1 firstCommandScheduler: RemoteCommandRetryScheduler request: RemoteCommand 16569204 -- target:mongo1:27017 db:local cmd:{ find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1488959328000|24 } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 60000, term: 18 } active: 1 callbackHandle.valid: 1 callbackHandle.cancelled: 0 attempt: 1 retryPolicy: RetryPolicyImpl maxAttempts: 1 maxTimeMillis: -1ms
2017-03-08T07:48:59.360+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:48:59.368+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:49:01.245+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:49:01.300+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:49:11.387+0000 I REPL     [replication-651] Restarting oplog query due to error: ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out, request was RemoteCommand 16569326 -- target:mongo1:27017 db:local expDate:2017-03-08T07:49:11.386+0000 cmd:{ getMore: 14646403649, collection: "oplog.rs", maxTimeMS: 5000, term: 18, lastKnownCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp 1488959340000|214, t: 18 } }. Last fetched optime (with hash): { ts: Timestamp 1488959341000|44, t: 18 }[-7957424638803321035]. Restarts remaining: 3
2017-03-08T07:49:11.387+0000 I REPL     [replication-651] Scheduled new oplog query Fetcher source: mongo1:27017 database: local query: { find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1488959341000|44 } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 60000, term: 18 } query metadata: { $replData: 1, $ssm: { $secondaryOk: true } } active: 1 timeout: 10000ms shutting down?: 0 first: 1 firstCommandScheduler: RemoteCommandRetryScheduler request: RemoteCommand 16569356 -- target:mongo1:27017 db:local cmd:{ find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1488959341000|44 } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 60000, term: 18 } active: 1 callbackHandle.valid: 1 callbackHandle.cancelled: 0 attempt: 1 retryPolicy: RetryPolicyImpl maxAttempts: 1 maxTimeMillis: -1ms
2017-03-08T07:49:23.570+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:49:23.583+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:50:18.323+0000 I REPL     [replication-644] Restarting oplog query due to error: ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out, request was RemoteCommand 16583477 -- target:mongo1:27017 db:local expDate:2017-03-08T07:50:18.323+0000 cmd:{ getMore: 15968275162, collection: "oplog.rs", maxTimeMS: 5000, term: 18, lastKnownCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp 1488959404000|1, t: 18 } }. Last fetched optime (with hash): { ts: Timestamp 1488959405000|16, t: 18 }[3811443744526174045]. Restarts remaining: 3
2017-03-08T07:50:18.323+0000 I REPL     [replication-644] Scheduled new oplog query Fetcher source: mongo1:27017 database: local query: { find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1488959405000|16 } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 60000, term: 18 } query metadata: { $replData: 1, $ssm: { $secondaryOk: true } } active: 1 timeout: 10000ms shutting down?: 0 first: 1 firstCommandScheduler: RemoteCommandRetryScheduler request: RemoteCommand 16583507 -- target:mongo1:27017 db:local cmd:{ find: "oplog.rs", filter: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1488959405000|16 } }, tailable: true, oplogReplay: true, awaitData: true, maxTimeMS: 60000, term: 18 } active: 1 callbackHandle.valid: 1 callbackHandle.cancelled: 0 attempt: 1 retryPolicy: RetryPolicyImpl maxAttempts: 1 maxTimeMillis: -1ms
2017-03-08T07:50:23.618+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Connecting to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:50:23.627+0000 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-RS-0] Successfully connected to mongo1:27017
2017-03-08T07:51:08.846+0000 I -        [shard registry reload] Invariant failure now() >= when src/mongo/executor/thread_pool_task_executor.cpp 295
2017-03-08T07:51:08.847+0000 I -        [shard registry reload] 

***aborting after invariant() failure


2017-03-08T07:51:08.907+0000 F -        [shard registry reload] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

 0x56044dbe5b81 0x56044dbe4c79 0x56044dbe515d 0x7f273fb20390 0x7f273f77b428 0x7f273f77d02a 0x56044ce73fd4 0x56044d977f18 0x56044d94f385 0x56044dcc3724 0x56044dcc3921 0x56044d94e48f 0x56044e6586f0 0x7f273fb166ba 0x7f273f84c82d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"56044C663000","o":"1582B81","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"56044C663000","o":"1581C79"},{"b":"56044C663000","o":"158215D"},{"b":"7F273FB0F000","o":"11390"},{"b":"7F273F746000","o":"35428","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7F273F746000","o":"3702A","s":"abort"},{"b":"56044C663000","o":"810FD4","s":"_ZN5mongo17invariantOKFailedEPKcRKNS_6StatusES1_j"},{"b":"56044C663000","o":"1314F18"},{"b":"56044C663000","o":"12EC385"},{"b":"56044C663000","o":"1660724","s":"_ZN4asio6detail9scheduler10do_run_oneERNS0_11scoped_lockINS0_11posix_mutexEEERNS0_21scheduler_thread_infoERKSt10error_code"},{"b":"56044C663000","o":"1660921","s":"_ZN4asio6detail9scheduler3runERSt10error_code"},{"b":"56044C663000","o":"12EB48F"},{"b":"56044C663000","o":"1FF56F0"},{"b":"7F273FB0F000","o":"76BA"},{"b":"7F273F746000","o":"10682D","s":"clone"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.4.2", "gitVersion" : "3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.4.0-64-generic", "version" : "#85-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 11:50:30 UTC 2017", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "56044C663000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5369A3377E676C284ECBB17624E909071B0846FC" }, { "b" : "7FFE4639E000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DA4CF76B76E77C8549F440C5059137F1C4809F3C" }, { "b" : "7F2740A9B000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7F514146540382F59AD705BA8C913A75204C6858" }, { "b" : "7F2740657000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E6D4D2E4A048992CD5501E5985094E6CEC6C5D4F" }, { "b" : "7F274044F000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A656E8087D6226AE46A173477B8B8E0767D559D9" }, { "b" : "7F274024B000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AFDCB9B3774F5AFE6EB3EC9A76A8BA159A17D5B6" }, { "b" : "7F273FF42000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4DBE0469DACBA00586428C9C7F4BBCEC8B6B1489" }, { "b" : "7F273FD2C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "68220AE2C65D65C1B6AAA12FA6765A6EC2F5F434" }, { "b" : "7F273FB0F000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4D7F52F335DC9665C2DCF308CE6514A6AE86DEDE" }, { "b" : "7F273F746000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "60131540DADC6796CAB33388349E6E4E68692053" }, { "b" : "7F2740D04000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "EA8652B03788783033C3AF093DFB71509C1378F8" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x56044dbe5b81]
 mongod(+0x1581C79) [0x56044dbe4c79]
 mongod(+0x158215D) [0x56044dbe515d]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7f273fb20390]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38) [0x7f273f77b428]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x16A) [0x7f273f77d02a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17invariantOKFailedEPKcRKNS_6StatusES1_j+0x0) [0x56044ce73fd4]
 mongod(+0x1314F18) [0x56044d977f18]
 mongod(+0x12EC385) [0x56044d94f385]
 mongod(_ZN4asio6detail9scheduler10do_run_oneERNS0_11scoped_lockINS0_11posix_mutexEEERNS0_21scheduler_thread_infoERKSt10error_code+0x324) [0x56044dcc3724]
 mongod(_ZN4asio6detail9scheduler3runERSt10error_code+0xD1) [0x56044dcc3921]
 mongod(+0x12EB48F) [0x56044d94e48f]
 mongod(+0x1FF56F0) [0x56044e6586f0]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x76BA) [0x7f273fb166ba]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7f273f84c82d]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

Updated the next day, one of the mongodb config server also crashed and below is the log:

```
2017-03-09T21:49:58.951+0000 I COMMAND  [conn1486] command config.lockpings command: findAndModify { findAndModify: "lockpings", query: { _id: "mongo4:27017:1489064656:-1939381939098694163" }, update: { $set: { ping: new Date(1489096198844) } }, upsert: true, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 15000 }, maxTimeMS: 30000 } planSummary: IDHACK update: { $set: { ping: new Date(1489096198844) } } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 nMatched:1 nModified:1 keysInserted:1 keysDeleted:1 numYields:0 reslen:435 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } }, Metadata: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } }, oplog: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } } } protocol:op_command 225ms
2017-03-09T21:50:09.811+0000 I COMMAND  [replSetDistLockPinger] command config.lockpings command: findAndModify { findAndModify: "lockpings", query: { _id: "ConfigServer" }, update: { $set: { ping: new Date(1489096209573) } }, upsert: true, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 15000 } } planSummary: IDHACK update: { $set: { ping: new Date(1489096209573) } } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 nMatched:1 nModified:1 keysInserted:1 keysDeleted:1 numYields:0 reslen:212 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } }, Metadata: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } }, oplog: { acquireCount: { w: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 237ms
2017-03-09T21:50:14.466+0000 I -        [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] Invariant failure now() >= when src/mongo/executor/thread_pool_task_executor.cpp 295
2017-03-09T21:50:14.466+0000 I -        [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] 

***aborting after invariant() failure


2017-03-09T21:50:14.705+0000 F -        [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

 0x560ec7876b81 0x560ec7875c79 0x560ec787615d 0x7f570798a390 0x7f57075e5428 0x7f57075e702a 0x560ec6b04fd4 0x560ec7608f18 0x560ec75e0385 0x560ec7954724 0x560ec7954921 0x560ec75df48f 0x560ec82e96f0 0x7f57079806ba 0x7f57076b682d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"560EC62F4000","o":"1582B81","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"560EC62F4000","o":"1581C79"},{"b":"560EC62F4000","o":"158215D"},{"b":"7F5707979000","o":"11390"},{"b":"7F57075B0000","o":"35428","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7F57075B0000","o":"3702A","s":"abort"},{"b":"560EC62F4000","o":"810FD4","s":"_ZN5mongo17invariantOKFailedEPKcRKNS_6StatusES1_j"},{"b":"560EC62F4000","o":"1314F18"},{"b":"560EC62F4000","o":"12EC385"},{"b":"560EC62F4000","o":"1660724","s":"_ZN4asio6detail9scheduler10do_run_oneERNS0_11scoped_lockINS0_11posix_mutexEEERNS0_21scheduler_thread_infoERKSt10error_code"},{"b":"560EC62F4000","o":"1660921","s":"_ZN4asio6detail9scheduler3runERSt10error_code"},{"b":"560EC62F4000","o":"12EB48F"},{"b":"560EC62F4000","o":"1FF56F0"},{"b":"7F5707979000","o":"76BA"},{"b":"7F57075B0000","o":"10682D","s":"clone"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.4.2", "gitVersion" : "3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.4.0-64-generic", "version" : "#85-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 11:50:30 UTC 2017", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "560EC62F4000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5369A3377E676C284ECBB17624E909071B0846FC" }, { "b" : "7FFDC055D000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DA4CF76B76E77C8549F440C5059137F1C4809F3C" }, { "b" : "7F5708905000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7F514146540382F59AD705BA8C913A75204C6858" }, { "b" : "7F57084C1000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E6D4D2E4A048992CD5501E5985094E6CEC6C5D4F" }, { "b" : "7F57082B9000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A656E8087D6226AE46A173477B8B8E0767D559D9" }, { "b" : "7F57080B5000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AFDCB9B3774F5AFE6EB3EC9A76A8BA159A17D5B6" }, { "b" : "7F5707DAC000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4DBE0469DACBA00586428C9C7F4BBCEC8B6B1489" }, { "b" : "7F5707B96000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "68220AE2C65D65C1B6AAA12FA6765A6EC2F5F434" }, { "b" : "7F5707979000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4D7F52F335DC9665C2DCF308CE6514A6AE86DEDE" }, { "b" : "7F57075B0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "60131540DADC6796CAB33388349E6E4E68692053" }, { "b" : "7F5708B6E000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "EA8652B03788783033C3AF093DFB71509C1378F8" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x560ec7876b81]
 mongod(+0x1581C79) [0x560ec7875c79]
 mongod(+0x158215D) [0x560ec787615d]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7f570798a390]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38) [0x7f57075e5428]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x16A) [0x7f57075e702a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17invariantOKFailedEPKcRKNS_6StatusES1_j+0x0) [0x560ec6b04fd4]
 mongod(+0x1314F18) [0x560ec7608f18]
 mongod(+0x12EC385) [0x560ec75e0385]
 mongod(_ZN4asio6detail9scheduler10do_run_oneERNS0_11scoped_lockINS0_11posix_mutexEEERNS0_21scheduler_thread_infoERKSt10error_code+0x324) [0x560ec7954724]
 mongod(_ZN4asio6detail9scheduler3runERSt10error_code+0xD1) [0x560ec7954921]
 mongod(+0x12EB48F) [0x560ec75df48f]
 mongod(+0x1FF56F0) [0x560ec82e96f0]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x76BA) [0x7f57079806ba]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7f57076b682d]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

From the log, I guess the mongod crash is related to [shard registry reload] and the mongodb config server is [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] ?

I have no idea what is happening. anybody can help?

Comment: Is there any more information before the backtrace?

Comment: @VinceBowdren Sure, please see the edited post.

Comment: Hmm, there's not much warning about anything going wrong. Have you investigated why those oplog queries are timing out?

Comment: @VinceBowdren Actually, I don't know

Comment: Have the same issue, it looks like it is fixed now: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27863